# Docker-compose, remote context, path relative to local machine instead of remote

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I have a very simple docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  containername:
    image: ${DOCKER_IMAGE}
    volumes:
      - ./config:/root/config
```

I'm using a remote staging server accessed via ssh:

```
docker context create staging --docker "host=ssh://ubuntu@staging.example.com"
docker context use staging
```

However, I see unexpected results with my volume after I `docker-compose up`:

```
docker-compose --context staging up -d
docker inspect containername
...
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/crummy/code/.../config",
                "Destination": "/root/config",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
...
```

It seems the expansion of `./config` to a full path happens *on the machine docker-compose is running on*. Not the machine Docker is running on.

I can fix this problem by hardcoding the entire path: `/home/ubuntu/config:/root/config`. But this makes my docker-compose file a little less flexible than it could be. Is there a way to get the dot expansion to occur on the remote machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the [docs say](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) that:

> You can mount a relative path on the host, which expands relative to the directory of the Compose configuration file being used. Relative paths should always begin with `.` or `..`

I believe that happens for two reasons:

1. There's no easy way and objective way that the `docker-compose` can find out how to expand `.` in this context, as there's no way to know what `.` would mean for the ssh client (home? same folder?).
2. Even though the `docker` cli is using a different context, the expansion is done by the `docker-compose` tool, that's unaware about the context switch.

Even using environment variables might pose a problem, since the env expansion would also happen in the machine you're running the `docker-compose` command.

Comment: That makes sense. I've hardcoded it instead, pity to lose the flexibility but that's OK.